# Flowmapper plugin will not load on QGIS Brighton

Tags: qgis-plugins, plugins

Iyi gunler Cem Bey, I have just installed QGIS 2.6 (Brighton) on my PC (Bootcamp) running Windows 7 and would like to try out FlowMapper. However after I have loaded it I received the following error:

Error Loading Plugin
The plugin seems to be invalid or have unfulfilled dependencies. It has been installed, but can't be loaded... Here is the error message below:

The plugin is broken. Python said:
ascii

Can you please help me solve this riddle?

Comment: I'd start python console and 'import ogr' command give errors! It's not a flowmapper pluging error seems more deeply programs.

Answer (score 2):

Resolved!
It's a module PATH Python console problem.

In QGIS Brighton/apps/Python27/Lib/site-packages create osgeo.pth (Administrators) file and put

# .pth file for the osgeo extensions
osgeo

start QGIS and install flowmapper ;)

Answer (score 1):

Merhaba Başak Hanım,

You could try manual installation if you are experiencing issues with automatic installation by using QGIS Plugin Manager.

FlowMapper is designed to be compatible with Windows, MacOS* and Linux platforms. It other words it has cross platform support. (*filtering options do not work under macos unless gdal/ogr dependencies are installed)

To manually install FlowMapper please **copy FlowMapper folder under the OS specific path given below.** Afterwards, restart QGIS and enable the plugin from plugin manager.

**Windows:** 
C:\Users\$USERNAME.qgis2\python\plugins\ 
or 
C:\Program Files\QGIS Dufour\apps\qgis\python\plugins\ 

**MacOS:**
./Users/$USERNAME/.qgis2/python/plugins/ 
or 
./usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/ 

**Linux:** 
home/$USERNAME/.qgis2/python/plugins/ 
or 
./Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python/plugins/